# SSIS/SSDT Testing Connectivity even when Work Offline is checked

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-2019

I have a SSIS solution containing two projects.  Both projects use parameterized project level connections, with the same connection properties.

I have checked Work Offline.  Project 1 opens just fine, with the connections correctly showing as offline.  Project 2 goes into a testing connectivity loop as soon as I open any package and never recovers.

If I wasn't working remote, I would just turn off the network to force offline, but that is not an option currently.

How can I bypass/exit the connectivity test, understanding that I cannot open any packages (or their properties)?

VS 2019, SSDT 3.15, connections to various database platforms and flat file, which all work in the other projects and solutions.

Comment: If the connections are parameterised, could you open the solution, clear out the parameters and then open the projects?  I would assume that with no connection details they would just error out rather than get stuck in a loop?

Comment: Good idea, but no change.

Comment: Is there a local instance you can point the parameterised connections to temporarily?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Many of the connections are enterprise or mainframe systems.